# In hibernate how to use not in clause

Tags: database, hibernate, jakarta-ee

i am having two table

jobs  and production

production table has jobid field which refers jobid of jobs table.

In hibernate how to use not in clause

to achieve following sql query

SELECT * FROM jobs where job_id  not in (select job_id from production);

Comment: hi i got answer it is very simple     Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(BwJobs.class);
            DetachedCriteria detachedcriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(BwProduction.class);
            detachedcriteria.setProjection(Property.forName("jobId"));

            criteria.add(Property.forName("jobId").notIn(detachedcriteria));


//            Query query = session.createQuery("from BwJobs");
            jobsList = criteria.list();

Answer (score 1):

You can use HQL:

```
List<Job> jobs = session.createQuery(
        "from Job where id not in (select jobId from Production)"
    ).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `not exist` keyword is a good choice.

Suppose I have a table called "giraffe", with id as primary key, and another table called "engineer" with a column called "giraffe" which refers to the "giraffe" table as foreign key, then the following HQL query worked for me:

```
from Giraffe giraffe where not exists (from Engineer as engineer where engineer.giraffe = giraffe.id )
```