# HQL - IN-clause with subquery on Many-to-Many association

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to get this query running

```
FROM Resource rs WHERE rs NOT IN (SELECT r.resources FROM Reservation r)
```

but Hibernate generates SQL code that leads to a SQL syntax exception.

How to avoid this without writing the SQL code by hand?

### Update

The workaround I'm using right now is to query the resources from all reservations first

```
SELECT r.resources FROM Reservation r
```

and then applying the second query

```
FROM Resource rs WHERE rs NOT IN (:resources_in_reservations)
```

Feels like an unnecessary step to me, but I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: As a work-around you can try to explicitly join on the primary keys, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694620/in-hibernate-how-to-use-not-in-clause

Comment: Btw, is `Reservation.resources` a collection, i.e. a ...ToMany relationship?

Comment: Yes it is Many-To-Many

Answer (score 0):

You can try with right outer join:

```
select rs 
from Reservation r right join r.resources rs
where r is null
```

Comment: This returns all resources, that are used in an reservation.

Comment: No, it returns all resources which are not related to any reservation: `where r is null`. Did you give it a try?

Comment: I tried it too, works correctly. What Hibernate version do you use?

Comment: The outcome you got happens when you specify `r is not null`. It has to be `r is null`.

Comment: 4.3.10.Final, I'm going to try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try use 'elements' function:

```
FROM Resource rs WHERE rs NOT IN (SELECT elements(r.resources) FROM Reservation r)
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html
Chapter: 14.10. Expressions