# "NOT IN" in HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, notin

I´m starting with Hibernate.

I have 2 tables in MySQL DB.

1)**Unit**

2)**type**: has as foreign key Unit_IdUnit
I have also in type a column name "Period" VARCHAR

I want to create this query on HQL:

```html
SELECT * 
FROM unit 
WHERE IdUnit not in(SELECT Unit_IdUnit 
                    FROM type 
                    WHERE Period='2016-09');
```

If I run this query in Mysql it´s working. But I can´t make it works on HQL.

How could I create this query to return a list of Unit?

**This is my first question, so please let me know if you need further information**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In hibernate how to use not in clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694620/in-hibernate-how-to-use-not-in-clause)

Comment: Please post your mappings and the error you get with your current solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below HQL:

```
session.createQuery(
        "from unit where IdUnit not in (SELECT Unit_IdUnit 
                    FROM type 
                    WHERE Period='2016-09')"
    ).list();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I fix it.

```html
Query query= session.createQuery("SELECT e1 FROM Unit e1 "
                               + "WHERE e1.idUnit NOT IN ("
                                                       + "SELECT e2.unit "
                                                       + "FROM type e2 "
                                                       + "WHERE e2.period=:period)");

query.setParameter("period", "2016-09");
list= query.list();
```